# What would happen if the FDA refused to follow the order on mifepristone?

Tags: united-states, judiciary, abortion, fda

Yesterday a Texas judge said the FDA’s 2000 approval of mifepristone – one of the drugs used to terminate a pregnancy – must be halted.

What would happen if the FDA said they refuse to follow that order?

Comment: This is too much speculation about the future. Nobody knows what would happen. Maybe ask for which legal escalation procedures the FDA has.

Comment: @Trilarion As it stands I don't feel there is speculation as there is another court order that is directing them to keep things as they are now and they would just be following the second court order.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to law.SE.  While questions about working of the government are on topic here, this particular question has already attracted one feel-good incorrect answer.  The fact that it has already attracted a speculative answer is a clear indication that it is *likely* to attract speculative answers here.  While on law.SE it may attract answer by community members who are more versed in the inner workings of the legal process.

Comment: @JoeW I understand the question about what would happen if the FDA simply didn't comply with the court order. I think this is a speculative scenario and the only real answer is that nobody knows. The existing answer answers a different question. Maybe the question should be adapted or clarified.

Comment: It seems like this question is only meaningful if you assume that the Texas ruling is eventually upheald, and wonders what the consequences are if a federal agency disregards a court order. Surely there is precedent on this general idea.

Comment: @JoeW But the question is still avout the future. We can just wait a bit and will find out, which is much better than to speculate. The curious thing here is that two courts decided different things. Surely there are precedents for that that one can ask about, independent of the FDA. For the FDA I would assume that it never refuses to follow an order. It might be unable to follow opposing orders at the same time but that's different from refusal. Refusal suggests that it's above the law.

Comment: @Barmar Lincoln (in)famously ignored a court invalidating his suspension of habeas corpus during the civil war.  Roosevelt threatened to basically do the same with some captured saboteurs (SCOTUS let him do as he wanted in the end; whether his blustering amounted to anything is uncertain, but I think typically considered unlikely).  The court has no power to force its decisions upon anyone.  The rest of the government has to voluntarily agree to abide by it, either out of sheer belief/respect, or political self-preservation, or power self-preservation (what if the others ignore *us* next?).

Comment: Just for the record. I voted that this question is about possible future action and too speculative, not that it's not about politics. I think it is about politics and somewhen in the future there will be an answer possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would be following the order of a different court that prevents them from making any changes on the status of that drug.

[Judges' dueling decisions put access to a key abortion drug in jeopardy nationwide](https://www.npr.org/2023/04/07/1159220452/abortion-pill-drug-mifepristone-judge-texas-amarillo)

> Within hours of that decision, U.S. District Judge Thomas O. Rice
> issued a ruling in a [separate case](https://www.npr.org/2023/02/24/1159375337/democratic-state-attorneys-general-sue-biden-administration-over-abortion-pill-r) in Washington state. That lawsuit
> filed by a coalition of Democratic attorneys general in 17 states and
> the District of Columbia sought to block the FDA from pulling the drug
> from the market.
>
> Rice's decision blocks the FDA from "altering the status quo and
> rights as it relates to the availability of Mifepristone."

Comment: Interesting. (The answer will be complete if you also add that in case of conflict between two court judgement, the case will go to a higher court whose decision the FDA will have to follow, unless it appeals it).

Comment: @sfxedit There are other ways to address these conflicting rulings. The DOJ has already appealed the Texas decision to the Fifth District, and one of the arguments will almost surely be that the parties that brought the claim had no standing. If that is found to be the case, the Texas decision becomes null and void.

Comment: @sfxedit Trying to get into that would make this answer way to long for this site as it is not as simple as you make it sound when you have a situation like this. As one court ruled in response to another it isn't that simple to decide.

Comment: This answer is entirely speculative.  It has no background information on how the conclusion, that this is how the law works, has been reached.  And it should be erased as pure misinformation (even if it's not technically disinformation).

Comment: @wrod What speculation? There is a court order stating that they should make no changes the the status and availability of the drug in question.

Comment: There's already a stay on the ruling because of the conflict. I think the question should be interpreted assuming that the Texas ruling is eventually upheald. It seems to be a question about how the court could enforce its ruling.

Comment: @Barmar: Assuming the circuit split ... that makes a mess. There's an unsolved debate from a few years ago about "cosmic injunctions"; the worst form being when two judges in two different circuits issue opposed injunctions that purport to cover the whole of the US. An immediate answer is divide by state, but that's a judgement call not a law answer.

Comment: @Joshua and an analysis elaborating on your comment should be the answer.  Not this "accepted" answer.  Which is why this answer should be deleted and the question should be migrated to law.SE.

Comment: @Barmar That is pure speculation as we can't predict the future and what the courts might rule. It is possible that this could go either way and we can't give a 100% accurate answer until such time that the ruling and actions take place.

Comment: @wrod If you feel that is the case you should provide an answer but as it stands the FDA would be following a court order if they did nothing in regards to the Texas court order.

Comment: @JoeW So we can't answer "What normally happens when a federal agency defies a court order?"

Comment: @Joshua My point is that for the purpose of answering this question, ignore the other court.

Comment: @Barmar And my answer is stating that they would be following the ruling of a court ruling that happened after the first one. We can't pick and choose which court rulings must be followed and there is a later court ruling that says they should not make any changes

Comment: @JoeW The question is only about one ruling. If the other ruling never happened, how does the court enforce an order against the FDA?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that a second ruling happened later and that impacts how things are going to work out.

Comment: @JoeW The intent of the question is clearly what would happen if this ruling takes precedence (it's expected that SCOTUS will decide which one stands). If the other ruling stands, this question is obviously moot.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't matter if the question is asking about the first court ruling if there is a second court ruling that says something else (what happened) or if a future ruling overturns the first court ruling. What you are asking for is speculation on what might have happened if no other court rulings happened and the FDA didn't follow the court order. The fact that the my answer is the accepted answer shows that it does indeed answer the question that the OP was asking.

Answer (score 4):

News update: This decision is being appealed. This answer will go out of date.

Further news update: Supreme Court has ordered a stay on the injunction. While we don't know yet, this usually signals they will take the case, which will most likely resolve the split.

The analysis below contains two "speed"-ish assumptions:

- SCOTUS has not yet resolved the curcuit split
- No new law as passed that changes the state.

The current status of the FDA's approval of mifepristone¹ is a court split in two different courts with dueling injunctions. Two judges in different circuits; neither of which can overrule the other, have issued opposed injunctions against the FDA.

When this happens at the district level; as a matter of law, the appellate court must resolve this. The affected should file for an emergency hearing to avoid contempt of court. However this *does not work* as a matter of law in different circuits. Neither circuit can directly overturn the other's ruling and the supreme court can only be compelled to hear a case in certain limited constitutional situations, none of which are in play here. (And even if we could compel the supreme court to hear it, the supreme court is capable of deadlocking due to a 4-4 ruling while trying to resolve a circuit split.)

Since the current situation is a known unresolved problem in procedural law; this is currently a matter of politics. Nobody actually believes the answer to dueling injunctions is "do what you want". Previously in the news there were headlines about splitting the action by state. That's a political decision, but not a terribly bad one.

I have previously approached problems like this one from the other direction. Does dividing the law itself by circuit create a problem. In this case I'm reasonably sure the answer is no. I cannot come up with a threat model where it being available in one district causes a risk to a district where it is not available, because as a prescription drug, providing it to other than the intended is already a crime. This presents a plausible political decision of let both rulings stand and constrain the rulings to the circuits they originated in. For the rest of the circuits; an action can be forced to issue a ruling to decide which way it will go in that district.

Another plausible answer is to do exactly what the headline said and break it down by state. The FDA's position as the sole authority stands challenged by several states (see medical marijuana and right to try acts). Would it be that crazy if the states claimed a constitutional issue under the theory of the Federal Government has enumerated powers to override individual FDA decisions by writing direct law? Probably not. I can see a lot of political pressure being brought to bear on this issue because of the use of the drug in question; but for arbitrary drugs the states decisions to allow certain drugs the FDA had not permitted (or outright banned) became a thing that was done. In the right to try cases it appeared the FDA didn't act out of something that looks like laziness, but in the marijuana cases it would appear that the result of a trial by jury was feared.

In politics, the power often ends up being where the people believe it is. This too is a plausible result. If the states say change it, and the people believe the power is with the states to change it, than the power is with the states to change it.

1: I am not discussing which ruling is right in this answer.

Comment: You seem to only envisage state laws in your answer.

Comment: @Fizz: Artifact of circuit split. The actual analysis assumes no new law passes. I just now edited the assumptions into the answer.

Comment: Congress can [also] override such splits. Unless it's about the constitutionality of something, which in this case it isn't. In the GED devices case, the FDA just lost and lost cases [on appeal too]. And they were actually Federal https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-care/appeals-court-axes-fda-ban-electric-shock-disabled-n1273572

Comment: @Fizz: It might be a constitutional issue. I find I can't predict the result of Congress passing a law on the matter.

Comment: "It might be a constitutional issue." Not under the present Texas decision. That simply ruled that the FDA didn't weigh the safety arguments properly.

Comment: OTOH I cannot entirely exclude that the current SCOTUS could simply rule FDCA unconstitutional out of their hat, even after 85 years or so of application. But since they upheld Obamacare by 7-2 [ok, technically the dismissed the challenger as lacking standing] and they only got one new judge in the meantime, the balance probably hasn't shifted enough on that, but who knows. Maybe they were just waiting for a better opportunity, on something that conservatives care more about.

Comment: But some of the conservative justices currently serving were on board with the Fed preemption doctrine in prior cases https://academic.oup.com/jlb/article/10/1/lsad005/7078178 , so this case is also far less of a slam dunk for hardcore conservatives [and state rights], if it comes to SCOTUS. But this isn't even a state rights issue as this point, it's whether the FDA properly applied the Federal law.

Comment: It's possible SCOTUS would again be creative and innovate on their recent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_questions_doctrine somehow here, but I don't see of top of my hat how. Time will tell.

Comment: @Fizz: I'm voting to reopen so you can write an answer.

Comment: After reading the actual decision by Kacsmaryk, I do see a way for the "major questions" to be applied here. Kacsmaryk ruled that "Chemical Abortion Drugs do not provide a Meaningful Therapeutic Benefit", so that they're essentially not like the other drugs that the FDA is explicitly allowed to regulate. A conservative SCOTUS could well agree with that, which would require Congress to explicitly include such drugs in FDA's mandate, in a special category. Which the current Congress might not be inclined to do.

Comment: "splitting the action by state" This would suggest that the same federal law is interpreted differently in different parts of the US? I think this poses lots of problems by itself and shouldn't be a preferred solution. Why is the obvious solution not to fix the underlying problem, i.e. make jurisprudence consistent in the US.

Comment: @Trilarion: The obvious solution has the greater problem of rendering a portion of the US subject to a court to which it cannot bring cases.

Comment: @Joshua There must be a practical and working solution to this. For example what about randomly assigning cases to each organizational unit on the same level and then having a clear hierarchy. Certainly one can make a legal system that scales up in some way instead of having a broken system one way or the other.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the government appealed the Texas decision. Then, a 5th Circuit panel [overturned](https://storage.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.ca5.213145/gov.uscourts.ca5.213145.183.2_1.pdf) in part the injunction by the Texas judge. In particular, the part where the original [2000] FDA decision had been deemed "reopened" was overturned (the panel ruled that the statute of limitations on challenging that had indeed passed/expired), but the rest of the injunction against the more recent FDA changes [2016+] which had broadened access to that drug were not overturned by that 5th Circuit 2-1 panel decision.

But the government was not satisfied with even with that result and appealed to SCOTUS, [which](https://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/courtorders/041423zr2_c9dh.pdf) temporarily stayed the whole [Texas] order, but this is really a very short term measure, as it expires on April 19. Journalists [have](https://www.texastribune.org/2023/04/14/supreme-court-fda-abortion-drug-mifepristone/) suggested that SCOTUS intends to provide a fuller response next week.

It's hard [for me] to speculate what the outcome of that might be. On one hand, even [sitting] conservative supreme justices like Alito [have](https://academic.oup.com/jlb/article/10/1/lsad005/7078178) previously sided with the FDA's preemption of state regulations on medications. On the other hand, the Texas' judge decision appears tailored to appeal to the recently [SCOTUS] minted [major questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_questions_doctrine) doctrine, because [it] asserts e.g. that "Pregnancy is not an illness" (p. 40) and that (p. 44) "Chemical Abortion Drugs do not provide a Meaningful Therapeutic Benefit", so that this drug should be held to a higher safety standard than the FDA decided. And, of course, we know that SCOTUS recently overturned *Roe. v Wade*, so the conservative majority thereof might be persuaded by such arguments on pregnancy.

On the enhanced access issue, even the 5th Circuit was miffed by FDA's decision to disregard their prior [black box warning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxed_warning) for this drug, which is essentially why they decided to not stay that part of the Texas injunction. So the FDA/government has much more of an uphill battle in that regard.

Finally, the FDA is actually very little on the hook here. SCOTUS [has](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1984/83-1878) previously decided (in *Heckler v. Chaney*) that the FDA can do selective enforcement of its own rules/prohibitions (particularly wrt. drugs used for the death penalty--which is hardly therapeutic either.) Furthermore, SCOTUS even ruled that that kind of FDA decision is not even subject to judicial review! It's more the case that manufacturers like Danco will have a tough time deciding what to do if they don't get official cover from the FDA, but will be subjected to contrary decisions at state level.

Also, if SCOTUS rules that regulating pregnancy termination drugs isn't  clearly spelled out in FDA's mandate, it's entirely possible that [a future] Congress could make that more clear by law. There is in fact [recent](https://www.wbur.org/onpoint/2023/02/10/why-congress-gave-the-fda-the-power-to-prohibit-off-label-uses-of-medical-devices) (2023) precedent for Congress doing that with respect to medical devices [for specific uses], after the FDA [lost](https://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-care/appeals-court-axes-fda-ban-electric-shock-disabled-n1273572) an appeal on that. Whether the current Congress has the majority/inclination to do something like that for pregnancy termination drugs is an interesting question that I won't try to address here.

[As for](https://www.cnbc.com/2023/04/13/abortion-pill-mifepristone-court-ruling-doesnt-affect-17-states-ag-says.html) the other decision mentioned in the accepted answer:

> The DOJ asked [Judge] Rice earlier this week to clarify by Friday what the government’s legal obligations are under his order because it sees “significant” tension with Kacsmaryk’s decision. Rice said on Thursday that Kacsmaryk’s order and the 5th Circuit ruling have no bearing on access to mifepristone in the 17 states and D.C.

So, the FDA had legal license to ignore the 5th Circuit decision in those 17 states + DC (which seem none were in the 5th Circuit). But Rice can't issue a decision escaping SCOTUS, of course.

Comment: Would it be possible to highlight a bit more which part of the answer is mostly answering the question? There seems the be a lot of context information (which is good but makes the answer a bit less focused).